# Intersection of string and string[]

Tags: javascript, typescript

What is the intersection of these types:

```
T1 = string
T2 = string[]
```

What is `T3 = T1 && T2`?

Is it `undefined` or is it `string`? When I tried to run it in VisualStudio Code, I got type of `string`, but can't it be `undefined` or something else?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, intersection types are defined using a single `&`. When you do `type T3 = string && string[]`, the right-hand expression evaluates to `string`, because of how logical [AND](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators) works, which is why your editor shows the new type as `string`.

To answer your question, `type T3 = string & string[]` will create a type that is *neither* `string` *nor* `undefined`. Hovering over a variable of type `T3` will show that it is simply the intersection of those two types.

However, having a type like that is senseless, since something cannot be both a `string` and a `string[]`, so you won't be able to assign anything to it.